# kivy-ios Build Failed with physical device (iPad Pro 10.5)

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, kivy

I'm trying to build the `touchtracer` example with physical device (iPad Pro 10.5).

And Xcode (8.3.3) on OSX 10.12.6 give me this message when debug:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Warning Group ld: warning: 
directory not found for option '-F/Users/<username>/kivy-ios/dist/frameworks'
Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group clang: error: 
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But with the simulator (iPad Pro 10.5), it's all good.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

I got my way out of this.

1. Project Setting > Build Settings > Enable Bitcode > Yes
2. Switch back to No
3. Clean & Build

And it works fine after that.